# Adding items to checklistbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a checklist control to my checklistbox using Jquery/Javascript.

I am using this code:

```
    function AddToClients(textValue, valueValue) {
        var tableRef =  document.getElementById('<%= chkEmailClients.ClientID %>');
        var tableRow = tableRef.insertRow();
        var tableCell = tableRow.insertCell();

        var checkBoxRef = document.createElement('input');
        var labelRef = document.createElement('label');

        checkBoxRef.type = 'checkbox';
        labelRef.innerHTML = textValue;
        checkBoxRef.value = valueValue;

        tableCell.appendChild(checkBoxRef);
        tableCell.appendChild(labelRef);
    }
```

If there is already an item in the checklistbox ontrol it works OK.

If there are no existing items I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertRow' of null

Any ideas why?

Comment: Check generated code for the line: "var tableRef =  document.getElementById('<%= chkEmailClients.ClientID %>');" to make sure you really give the ID selector to the function.

Comment: Is your chkEmailClients.ClientID HTML control rendered if empty?

Comment: @Minister Hi, yes I did that and it is an object.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson:is `insertRow` user defined method ?

Comment: I didn't understand which is an object? It should be ID string, pointing to an HTML element with the same ID. The function  document.getElementById() returns object, but according to your error - it's null: Cannot call method 'insertRow' of null

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward yes, it is rendered...

Comment: yes, it is a valid client ID. The very fact that I can add an item when one exists means that part of the code is OK

Comment: @close why the close?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson:  aah, then i beleive when the table is null , the functions associated to it would be undefined as well as the object `chkEmailClients.` which is returned would be `null`. hence u getting that error

Comment: this is the dom/markuo when no items exists  <table id="chkEmailClients">
 <tbody>
</tbody></table>

Comment: @close why flag as off-topic for?

Comment: @dreamweiver Yes, i just checked and the object is undefined. So, how can i add a listitem?  Any ideas? Thanks for your time

Comment: @AndrewSimpson: simple and easy technique would be to just create a dummy row over the table initially and hide it if possible, then try adding/deleting the rows over it.

Comment: hi, what i am going to do is always have 1 item in the listbox.  If no valid entries that the item will say 'no items'. Jiust trying to figure out how to change the text value ;)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson: u dont need to retain that  invalid row once u start adding the real rows, so what u can do is , just delete the invalid/default row before adding any row.  similarly, when deleting the last row add the same dummy row back again. this way you could retain consitency

Comment: Hi, that is exactly what I am trying to do at this moment.  This works if I have a valid item and I delete it. It display 'no items' OK. But if I add a valid item next I get both entries displayed.  I have tried removing the 'no items' before and after inserting the new valid row but i still get both items displaying.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45860/discussion-between-dreamweiver-and-andrew-simpson)